# React-Webcam Recording, Replay, Re-recording, Storing server sent data problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, blob, video-recording

when I wanna sent a video with Axios post request
as a file into form data then the result is shown backend server undefined.
how can I send the video properly
how can send it to the server as form data ?

I tried hard but there has no solution.
how can store web came video on the server-side.
how can work Blob file

```
import React, {useEffect} from "react";
import Webcam from "react-webcam";
import axios from 'axios';
import {BaseUrl} from '../../utils/constant';
import { FilePond, File, registerPlugin } from 'react-filepond'


 const WebcamStreamCapture = () => {
    const webcamRef = React.useRef(null);
    const mediaRecorderRef = React.useRef(null);
    const [capturing, setCapturing] = React.useState(false);
    const [recordedChunks, setRecordedChunks] = React.useState([]);
    const [videoSrc, setVideoSrc] = React.useState(null);
    const isInitialMount = React.useRef(true);

    useEffect(() => {
      if (isInitialMount.current) {
        isInitialMount.current = false;
      } else {
        if (!capturing) {
          // console.log('running handleDownload')
          handleDownload();
        }
      }
    }, [recordedChunks])

    const handleStartCaptureClick = React.useCallback(() => {
      setCapturing(true);
      mediaRecorderRef.current = new MediaRecorder(webcamRef.current.stream, {
        mimeType: "video/webm"
      });
      mediaRecorderRef.current.addEventListener(
        "dataavailable",
        handleDataAvailable
      );
      mediaRecorderRef.current.start();
      console.log("mediaRecorderRef.current.state", mediaRecorderRef.current.state);  // "recording"
    }, [webcamRef, setCapturing, mediaRecorderRef]);
  
    const handleDataAvailable = React.useCallback(
      ({ data }) => {
        if (data.size > 0) {
          setRecordedChunks((prev) => prev.concat(data));
        }
      },
      [setRecordedChunks]
    );
  
    const handleStopCaptureClick = React.useCallback(() => {
      mediaRecorderRef.current.stop();
      setCapturing(false);
    }, [mediaRecorderRef, webcamRef, setCapturing]);
        const handleDownload = React.useCallback(() => {
      if (recordedChunks.length) {
        const blob = new Blob(recordedChunks, {
          type: "video/webm"
        });
        const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        const video = document.getElementById("video-replay");
        video.src = url
        const file=video 
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("file", blob);
        axios.post(BaseUrl+"/upload", formData)

      
      }
    }, [recordedChunks]);

    return (
         <>
           <div className="d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
        <Webcam audio={false} ref={webcamRef} height={400} width={500}/>
        <video id="video-replay"   height="400" width="500" controls></video>
        {capturing ? (
          <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={handleStopCaptureClick}>Stop Capture</button>
        ) : (
          <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={handleStartCaptureClick}>Start Capture</button>
        )}
        {recordedChunks.length > 0 && (
          <div>
            <button onClick={handleDownload}>Download</button>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
      {/* from vilidation : */}
   
         </>
    );
};
export default WebcamStreamCapture
```

my server code is :

```
var storage = new GridFsStorage({
  url: 'mongodb+srv://arefin:arefin@cluster0.xl4t5.mongodb.net/flip-cart?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
  fromData: (req, file) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const filename = `video-${Date.now()}${path.extname(file.originalname)}`;
                const fileInfo = {
          filename: filename,
          bucketName: 'uploads'
        };
        resolve(fileInfo);
      });
  }
});

    app.post("/api/upload", (req, res) => {
      console.log("req.file", req.body);
    
    res.json({ file: req.file });
    console.log( res.json({ file: req.file }));
    });
```

Comment: Welcome! Please format your code snippet properly!